# Proc means output data set

Tags: sas

How do you output a data set from proc means with multiple metrics? The below code is what I have now but am not sure how to edit it to make it correct. I want the sum,mean,ans max in the output data set.

```
proc means data = blah;
output out = cool mean = sum = max=;
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
proc means data=sashelp.class;
var age height weight;
output out=want mean= sum= max= /autoname;
run;
```

You can also specify explicit names.

```
output out=want mean(age)=age_mean sum(age)=age_sum;
```