# PROC MEANS Output MIN MAX MEDIAN for ALL numeric variables

Tags: sas

I have a similar situation to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732746/proc-means-output-data-set).  However, I don't want to list my 300 variable names in the `var` statement since they are all unique.  Is there a way to use `proc means` or `proc summary` to output summary statistics for all the numeric variables in one data set?

I've tried:

```
proc means data=my_data min median max;
    output out=summary_data min=min median=median max=max;
run;
```

But this only outputs the summary statistics for the first variable.  I have also tried with the help of `ods trace`:

```
proc means data=my_data min median max;
    ods output Summary=summary_data;
run;
```

Which gives me the summary statistics for all the variables, but still in one row:

```
VName_VAR1 VAR1_Minimum VAR1_Median VAR1_Maximum VName_VAR2 VAR2_Minimum etc...
VAR1       3            3           3            VAR2       3
```

Where my VAR names are all unique. Is there some other way to use `proc means` or `proc summary` to output summary statistics for all the numeric variables in one data set?

UPDATE:

When I removed `min=min median=median max=max`:

```
proc means data=my_data min median max;
    output out=summary_data;
run;
```

The code then produces the output:

```
 Obs  _TYPE_ _FREQ_ _STAT_   VAR_1    VAR_2 ... etc

 1    0      91     N          91.00  91    ... etc
 2    0      91     MIN      2005.00  13         .
 3    0      91     MAX      2014.00  13         .
 4    0      91     MEAN     2009.34  13         .
 5    0      91     STD         3.02   0
```

However, it still doesn't give me the MEDIAN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I transpose the data before using `proc means` I get the desired output.

```
proc sort data=sashelp.cars out=cars; by _character_;run;

proc transpose data=cars out=cars_t;
  var _numeric_;
  by _character_;
run;

proc sort data=cars_t;by _name_;run;

proc means data=cars_t noprint;
  output out=cars_summary(drop = _type_ _freq_) min=min median=median max=max;
  by _name_;
run;
```

The code then produces the output:

```
Obs    _NAME_             min     median         max

 1    Cylinders          3.0        6.0        12.0
 2    EngineSize         1.3        3.0         8.3
 3    Horsepower        73.0      210.0       500.0
 4    Invoice         9875.0    25294.5    173560.0
 5    Length           143.0      187.0       238.0
 6    MPG_City          10.0       19.0        60.0
 7    MPG_Highway       12.0       26.0        66.0
 8    MSRP           10280.0    27635.0    192465.0
 9    Weight          1850.0     3474.5      7190.0
10    Wheelbase         89.0      107.0       144.0
```

This works if you have a unique id for each row in your original data.

Comment: +1 this is excellent, I wish I could mark this the answer instead of mine!  I am always looking for ways to reduce my over-reliance on macros.  I was unaware of the `_CHARACTER_` and `_NUMERIC_` special variables, for example.  I'm going to hang out in the chat room for awhile in case you wish to speak more.

Comment: +1 Better than my answer as you can request other univariate stats such as mean, standard deviation, etc.  Still shouldn't be this hard however...

Answer (score 2):

If you're just after min / med / max then the following will work (such that you don't have to name the variables):-

```
ods output quantiles = quantiles;
proc univariate data = sashelp.cars;
  var _numeric_;
proc sort;
  by varname;
run;

proc transpose data = quantiles out = quan_tran (drop=_name_ rename=(_100__max = max _50__median = median _0__min = min));
  by varname;
  var estimate;
  id quantile;
  where quantile in: ('100', '50', '0');
run;
```

If you want other types of measures - mean, std, etc. - proc univariate outputs them in separate datasets meaning you'd have merge tables and etc. etc. - it turns into a pain again.

The output datasets from SAS can really be puzzlingly bad with proc means, for me, being the most egregious example.

Comment: I agree. Another way I discovered it works is to transpose the data first, so that the variable names are in a column.  Sort by variable names and then use the `by` statement in `MEANS procedure`.

Comment: Agreed also re SAS output datasets. +1 for showing a good example of using ODS to programmatically store data.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the stackods option in the means statement?

```
ods listing close;
ods output summary=s;
proc means data=mydata stackods min median max;
run;
ods output close;
ods listing;
proc print;
run;
```

Comment: OP is long gone, but this is probably the best solution here.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

Here is a macro-based solution, with new step-by-step comments added.  It uses metadata from the SAS `dictionary.columns` to discover all numeric variables in a dataset.  Basically, I take the `MIN`, `MEDIAN`, and `MAX` of all the numeric variables, outputting the results in three separate datasets. I then concatenate the datasets, using the `IN` variable to figure out where each row is coming from and thus labeling it with the appropriate statistic name.  The output is then three rows and `n` columns.

As the OP demonstrated in his answer, the whole macro / meta-data thing to get the numeric variables can all be replaced by simply using the special `_NUMERIC_` variable.  I will leave my current approach in place in case someone is interested in using it for other things.

Furthermore, the OP's answer is a macro-free solution that uses `PROC TRANSPOSE` to get to the same place as this one, without any concatenation of separate result sets.  I urge all readers to review it as it is more "SAS-like".

```
%GLOBAL 
    var_names 
    dsn_temp_min
    dsn_temp_median
    dsn_temp_max
; 
%LET dsn_temp_min = min_summary ;
%LET dsn_temp_median= med_summary;
%LET dsn_temp_max= max_summary;

/* Identify dataset */
%LET lib_name = WORK ;  /* change to your library */
%LET dsn = my_data ;

/* Retrieve numeric variable names from SAS metadata and store in `var_name` */
/* macro variable. Library and dataset name must be upper-case since that is */
/* how they are stored in `dictionary.columns`. */
/* UPDATE: this all can be avoided by just using the _NUMERIC_ special variable */
/* but I am leaving this in here in case anyone is interested in querying */
/* meta-data for other purposes. */

%LET lib_name = %UPCASE (&lib_name);
%LET dsn = %UPCASE (&dsn);

PROC SQL NOPRINT;
    SELECT name
    INTO :var_names SEPARATED BY ' '
    FROM dictionary.columns
    WHERE libname = "&lib_name"
    AND memname = "&dsn"
    AND type ^= "char"
;
QUIT;
RUN;

/* Take the MIN of all numeric variables and store in a separate dataset */
PROC MEANS DATA = &lib_name..&dsn NOPRINT ;
    OUTPUT OUT=&dsn_temp_min (DROP = _TYPE_ _FREQ_)
        MIN (&var_names) = 
    ;
RUN;

/* Take the MEDIAN of all numeric variables and store in a separate dataset */    
PROC MEANS DATA = &lib_name..&dsn NOPRINT ;
    OUTPUT OUT=&dsn_temp_median (DROP = _TYPE_ _FREQ_)
        MEDIAN (&var_names) = 
    ;
RUN;

/* Take the MAX of all numeric variables and store in a separate dataset */        
PROC MEANS DATA = &lib_name..&dsn NOPRINT ;
    OUTPUT OUT=&dsn_temp_max (DROP = _TYPE_ _FREQ_)
        MAX (&var_names) = 
    ;
RUN;


/* Concatenate the three separate datasets into one.  Use IN to figure out */
/* where each row is coming from, and label appropriately */
DATA summary_data;
    LENGTH stat $6 ;

    RETAIN
        stat &var_names
    ;

    SET 
        &dsn_temp_min (IN=s1)
        &dsn_temp_median (IN=s2)
        &dsn_temp_max (IN=s3)
    ;

    IF (s1) THEN DO;
        stat = "MIN" ;
    END;
    ELSE IF (s2) THEN DO;
        stat = "MEDIAN" ;
    END;
    ELSE IF (s3) THEN DO;
        stat = "MAX" ;
    END;

    LABEL stat = "Statistic";
RUN;
```

Comment: Makes sense.  I was looking for a solution without using a `var` statement.  It just seems odd that the listing output from my first try did print what I wanted, but would only output the first line to my data set.  For the second... who knows why SAS outputs the data all into one row.

Comment: For the first, because you have no `var`, SAS looks for the analysis variables to be specified in the `OUTPUT` statement, e.g. `OUTPUT . . . MIN (var_1 var_2 ....) =`.  Not finding that, it just defaults to the first variable.  I'm not as sure about the second, because I don't often use ODS for selecting pieces of the output, but I guess the ODS `Summary` element is formatted that way.

Comment: I just realized from looking at your code if I do:
    `proc means data=my_data min median max;
        output out=summary_data;
    run;`
Removing `min=min median=median max=max` then it works as I expected.

Comment: Neither my code nor yours outputs the median.  I may be stuck with my one row of output and using `proc transpose` to get the output into a more user friendly table.

Comment: The format you are looking for - is it 3 rows (MIN, MEDIAN, MAX) and `n` columns for the variables?  Or is it one row with unique names for `n x 3` columns?

Comment: See most recent edit to code - let me know if this is what you meant.

Comment: Ideally n rows and 3 columns just like the `proc means` listing output.  I know how to manipulate it to get that structure with other procedures in SAS, but is there a way to get an output table which is the same as the output listing without manipulating it afterwards?

Comment: Yeah basically I had to manipulate it... I know no way of doing it in one `PROC MEANS`/`OUTPUT` step.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52630/discussion-between-mark-nielsen-and-sparc-spread)

Comment: Good idea, can we do it tomorrow though - I have to leave work now.